# visual sql query generator for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my RoR app I need to develop a visual query generator as similar as possible to the one provided by MS ACCESS. (sample screenshot of how this looks in ms access)

[image]

The user would be able to choose db tables, from the tables choose fields and then add conditions to the fields.

Is there any gem / code that you are aware of, that would help me in this endavour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would need a lot of TLC to get to be like the MS Access Query, but you could use the Ransack gem to accomplish the queries and nested associations.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack

Comment: I was hoping to find something more suitable. But thank you for pointing out something that goes into the right direction!